# Declaring global inside a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, global

Lately, I've had to write functions that look like this:

```
fruits = []
def foo():
    global fruits
    ...
```

What exactly does the line `global fruits` do? I apologize if this question has been asked before, but I could not find one like this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693120/use-of-global-keyword-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It tells the compiler that binding the name should be performed in the module scope rather than the local scope. It has no use if you're simply mutating the object (e.g. `fruits.append('apple')`).